# How to sort files by type in folder view of Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using *Visual Studio Code*, how can I sort files by type when I open folder view?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

To sort the files of the explorer view by type, add the following option to your user settings (`settings.json`):

```json
"explorer.sortOrder": "type"
```

This feature is available since vscode [release 1.15](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_15#_file-explorer-sort-order)

Answer (score 27):

search "explorer" in settings page and you can change the control of sorting order there.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems that [from version 1.67](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_67#_explorer-file-nesting) there are new values for this setting, for example, to support file nesting like this one:

`"explorer.sortOrder": "foldersNestsFiles"`

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be a way to specify a "full extension" to sort by though:

```
app.component.css
grid.component.css
app.component.html
grid.component.html
app.component.ts
grid.component.ts
app.model.ts
grid.model.ts
```

Comment: Question does not look like asking for "full extension".